# Assign Module Value to Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

Is there a way to use a module like recursive-readdir as such:

```
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir');

var files = recursive-readdir(dir);
```

Instead of:

```
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir');

recursive('some/path', function (err, files) {
  // Files is an array of filename 
  console.log(files);
});
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are looking for a _synchronous_ method. The second snippet uses an asynchronous method, that's why it has a _callback_ function.